# Is there a standard URN scheme for TETRA devices?

Tags: urn

Is there a definition (a standard) of an URN scheme for tetra devices? (TETRA as Terrestrial Trunked Radio)

I found many pages about the SSI and ITSI (individual Tetra subscriber identity) but nowhere a URN scheme for that. Would be nice if there is already some standard for it so i dont have to define one myself.

Answer (score 1):

No.

All URN namespaces are registered on http://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces. There doesn’t seem to be one for [TETRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio).